# Colapsar arbol <li><ul>

Tags: bootstrap, lista, sourcetree

Este código  no es mio, lo encontré en internet, me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que aparezca colapsado.
[Bootstrap 3.0 tree](http://jsfiddle.net/jayhilwig/hv8vU/)

```js
$(function () {
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Collapse this branch');

    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-minus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

```css
.tree {
    min-height:20px;
    padding:19px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
.tree li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 5px 0 5px;
    position:relative
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
    content:'';
    left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:auto
}
.tree li::before {
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    bottom:50px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    width:1px
}
.tree li::after {
    border-top:1px solid #999;
    height:20px;
    top:25px;
    width:25px
}
.tree li span {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 8px;
    text-decoration:none
}
.tree li.parent_li>span {
    cursor:pointer
}
.tree>ul>li::before, .tree>ul>li::after {
    border:0
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
    height:30px
}
.tree li.parent_li>span:hover, .tree li.parent_li>span:hover+ul li span {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #94a0b4;
    color:#000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree well">
    <ul>
        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> Parent</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                    <ul>
                                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> Parent2</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Disculpa a que te refieres con colapsado? A que aparezcan las carpetas raíz solo y que se despliegue si le das 'click'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes añadirle que te "seleccione" las etiquetas que son sub-listas de las listas principales `parent_li` y mediante `.hide('fast')` que te las oculte.

```
parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li').hide('fast');
```

```js
$(function () {
    //Aquí añades la clase y le índicas que los sub-directorios o sub-listas, esten en oculto 
    $('.tree li:has(ul)').addClass('parent_li').find(' > span').attr('title', 'Expand').parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li').hide('fast'); 

    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-plus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse').find(' > i').addClass('glyphicon-minus-sign').removeClass('glyphicon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

```css
.tree {
    min-height:20px;
    padding:19px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#fbfbfb;
    border:1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
}
.tree li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 5px 0 5px;
    position:relative
}
.tree li::before, .tree li::after {
    content:'';
    left:-20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:auto
}
.tree li::before {
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    bottom:50px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    width:1px
}
.tree li::after {
    border-top:1px solid #999;
    height:20px;
    top:25px;
    width:25px
}
.tree li span {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px 8px;
    text-decoration:none
}
.tree li.parent_li>span {
    cursor:pointer
}
.tree>ul>li::before, .tree>ul>li::after {
    border:0
    visibility: hidden;
}
.tree li:last-child::before {
    height:30px
}
.tree li.parent_li>span:hover, .tree li.parent_li>span:hover+ul li span {
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #94a0b4;
    color:#000
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree well">
    <ul>
        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> Parent</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                    <ul class="no-visible">
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                    <ul>
                                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Great Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Grand Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i> Parent2</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></i> Child</span>  <a href="">Goes somewhere</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```